# How to use IIS app pool identity to execute sql queries in ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis

I have an ASP.NET application that needs to execute some sql queries. I am getting Access Is Denied because it appears the queries are not being executed as the app pool identity (which is the user that has access to sql). Do I need to change my connection string? It currently looks like this: `"Data Source=DbServerName;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"`. Or is there an IIS setting to do this?

Comment: I take it this is on an `Intranet` with `AD` and Windows Login?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){});